# How can I create a subdomain on my GitHub Pages site?

Tags: html, github-pages

I have a GitHub pages site with a custom domain, like https://example.com. How can I create a subdomain, such as https://blog.example.com? I've seen guides that require for you to create a new repository, but I'm not sure if that's what I'm going for here. I have GitHub Education and access to my website's DNS records. I am not using a Jekyll theme, I wrote my website from scratch. Any ideas on how I can create a subdomain in this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the same with following attached link please follow those steps.

https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-a-subdomain